# Can I restrict access to websites (list of available) for myself?

Tags: permissions

I need access to the Internet at work, but I'm addicted to click on evil websites (world news, political, sports, anything that makes for a while I'm gone) that scatter my concentration. This is sickness and I can't control that.

I'm Ubuntu(14.04) user for 3 days. In Windows I used Microsoft Parent Control to set permissions for websites. I made random password to access Parent account, printed and I hid the piece of paper with password in an uncomfortable spot in the basement. It does the trick.

How to do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can just install one of the many browser add-ons that do exactly what you need.

I don't know which browser you're using, but here's a list of them for firefox (parental control category):
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=parental+control&cat=all

and here is a particular one (first goole hit), maybe it's perfect for you:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/

EDIT:
Of course, if you use some other browser, use its add-on store (or whatever it's called) to find what you're looking for.

Comment: bad idea. I may install any other browser at any time to avoid permission.

Comment: Addicted huh? :-) Any way, all browsers have add-ons for this.

Comment: or just disable addon

Answer (score 0):

You can edit:

```
/etc/hosts
```

to map the website names to a dummy ip. Then whenever you try to connect to said websites it will try to connect to dummy ip. Typically 0.0.0.0 is used as the dummy ip.

For example:

```
0.0.0.0 facebook.com badsites.com
```

You might need to restart the network service/reboot

Comment: but I can manipulate this hosts file at any time.  Easy to add permission, easy to remove permission back.